# Javascript to format date value

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I am trying (and failing!) to format my date output using javascript, so I am asking for some help.

The date format is 2013-12-31 (yyyy-mm-dd), but I want to display the date as 12-2013 (mm-yyyy).

I have read many posts, but I am now just confused.

Here is the call to the javascript function:

```
changeDateFormat($('#id_award_grant_date').val()),
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
 function changeDateFormat(value_x){


 }
```

Comment: Split the date in parts by `-` then join the parts as you like.

Comment: It might be overkill for what you want to achieve but I really like the javascript date library Moment.js http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is just a string, so just split it and put it back together in the wanted format

```
var date     = '2013-12-31',
    parts    = date.split('-'),
    new_date = parts[1]+'-'+parts[0];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jgtM/)

Comment: Thanks! So easy when you are not a noob like me!

Comment: What a lazy programmer like me would do: `[parts[1],parts[0]].join("-");` if you have many items to combine.

Comment: @user1261774 - hopefully this isn't a datepicker? If it where you should probably be using some of the built in methods instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
var d = '2013-12-31'
var yyyymmdd = d.split('-')
var mmyyyy = yyyymmdd[1]+'-'+yyyymmdd[0]; // "12-2013"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with `split` and `join`.

```
var yyyymmdd = '2013-12-31'.split('-'),
    mmyyyy = [ yyyymmdd[1], yyyymmdd[0] ].join('-');

console.log('The date is: ', mmyyyy );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeDateFormat(str) {
    var reg = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/;
    var match = str.match(reg);
    return match[2] + "-" + match[1];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wZrYD/

Comment: Good stuff, the regex solution here is the only solution here even attempting to validate that the input is numeric. I managed to whittle it down to one line in the function using regex replace http://jsfiddle.net/wZrYD/2/

Comment: i learn a lot from your update: 1.strict validate 2.replace() is more elegant(my solution is ugly). thanks for you feedback @MatthewLock  :)